# Find the nearest match that could add up to zero in SAS

Tags: sas

I am using SAS for research. My question is how to find the nearest match in the same column. Please see the following for a quick illustration. I am new to SAS programming, and only have a preliminary guess that proc sql might do the work. What I am doing now is manually adjusting - it is painful and especially so for over 3,000 observations.

[image: The data I have]

I want to find the nearest "Value" match that could add up to zero. For example, for firm AA in 1st quarter 2000, I want to match the nearest two numbers that could add up to 100. I don't want the 50 for firm AA in 2002Q2 nor firm BB 2000Q4. In addition, I also struggle with the case for firm BB, and have no idea how to perform the matching: the two negative numbers add up to -200, the two positive numbers add up to +200, and they maybe in same or different years. To help you understand better, please find the following table for what I have in mind at the end of the day:

[image: The data I want]

For the BB case, it can be 2001Q3 "-100" matched to "50" in 2000Q4, it is also fine if it matches to "100" in 2001Q1 - the order doesn't matter. Thanks in advance! Any help is really appreciated!

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Can you describe the match process in more detail ? The sample only shows cases of sequentially selected values that sum to 0.  Suppose AA 2001 Q3 was 101, would the -50 from AA 2001 Q2 match to +50 for AA 2002 Q2 ?  Are you looking for arbitrary combinations (within firm) that sum to 0 ?

Comment: An interesting variation on [an NP-complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)...

Comment: @user667489 I agree. Optmodel looks like it would be a good option here, if he has access to OR.

Comment: If you don't have SAS/OR, I suggest you have a go at implementing the algorithm from [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) of the Wikipedia article, then post another qustion if you get stuck. As posted, the question is too broad.

Comment: @Richard I would like to find all "nearest" combinations that sum to zero within firm. By nearest, I mean +/- two quarters - in your question, 2001Q2 shouldn't be relevant to 2002Q2. But 2001Q4 -50 should also be matched to 2002Q2 50 (which is missing from my original post)

Comment: @user667489 thanks for pointing to the subset sum problem. I have SAS/OR and I tried to teach myself Proc optmodel but no success. Maybe I am not a quick learner or I misunderstand something, but from what I understand in optmodel you have to specify an optimization function for some variables. Here, my problem is find all possible nearest combination that sum to zero - first, I don't know if it is an "optimization"; second, it could be x1+x2+x3=0, it could also be x4+x6+x8=0 we don't know before, how would you write your optimization function in this case? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

At +/- 2 quarters, each row has at most 5 items that need to be to checked in combination.

There are 15 combinations that include the current row (0 column) and at least one other row.

```
combo   -2  -1  0   1   2
1       *   *   *       
2       *       *       
3           *   *       
4       *   *   *   *   
5       *       *   *   
6           *   *   *   
7               *   *   
8       *   *   *   *   *
9       *       *   *   *
10          *   *   *   *
11              *   *   *
12      *   *   *       *
13      *       *       *
14          *   *       *
15              *       *
```

You could check all these combinations for each row to find your cases 'of sums to zero' in the context of combinations with replacement.